# How to expose TCP service on IPv6 (GKE)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to expose kubernetes TCP service on public IPv6 address. Application is working fine on IPv4 but I can't configure it on IPv6. The problem is that this is not HTTP service. 
Current service is done by type: LoadBalancer on non standard port 11042. So I think it creates network load balancer.

Following the documentation forwarding rules supporting IPv6 are Target HTTP proxy
Target HTTPS proxy, Target SSL proxy, Target TCP proxy but TCP proxy has closed list of ports that can be used. I was also trying to use Ingress but it looks like on google it only supports HTTP/S. Is any other way to expose TCP service on public IPv6?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As for now [Network Loadbalancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network) doesn't support **IPv6**. Note that this is the only **pass-through** load balancer currently available on **GCP**. Compare it with [Summary of Google Cloud load balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#summary-of-google-cloud-load-balancers) table.

Only **proxy** loadbalancers such as **HTTP/HTTPS Loadbalancers** and **TCP Proxy/SSL Proxy** do support **IPv6** (compare with [IPv6 termination for HTTP(S), SSL Proxy, and TCP Proxy Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6))

As you can read in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network):

> Because the load balancer is a pass-through load balancer, your
>   backends terminate the load-balanced TCP connection or UDP packets
>   themselves.

As you may already know (and you can read about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc)) for the time being **GCP VPC** and **GCE instances** support only **IPv4 connectivity**:

> VPC networks only support IPv4
>   [unicast](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicast) traffic. They do **not**
>   support
>   [broadcast](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_(networking)),
>   [multicast](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast), or IPv6 traffic
>   *within* the network; VMs in the VPC network can only send to IPv4 destinations and only receive traffic from IPv4 sources. However, it
>   is possible to create an IPv6 address for a [global load
>   balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6).

As you already mentioned **TCP Proxy** and **SSL Proxy** **do not support arbitrary destination ports**. Only well-know ports listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#summary-of-google-cloud-load-balancers) are supported. Arbitrary ports can be used only with **External Network TCP/UDP** loadbalancer but because of lack of the support for **IPv6** you cannot use it.

**As to your particular use case the conclusion is that at the moment it cannot be done the way you want.**

Does your backend really have to be exposed on this non standard port ? - I assume you have good reasons for using it so most probably changing it for some well-known port is not even an option.

*The problem is that this is not HTTP service.* - If it was **http** service but only exposed on some arbitrary port then you could use **ingress**. If it was the case you would simply create an **ingress** which forwards the request to one of your backend `Services` like in [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services) example. Ingress backends can really use **arbitrary ports**, but **not arbitrary protocols** - that's the point. The underlying application layer protocol has to be **http**. So if your service uses some completely different protocol you may forget about **ingress** right away.

You actually answered your question yourself. I see that you went through the docs and analyzed quite thoroughly all available solutions already, ruling out those which don't meet your requirements. Well... I can only confirm it with this summary. I hope it can be helpful even though it doesn't provide the solution that you are looking for.